# Include ZEND framework 2.3 in application without skeleton

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx, zend-framework2

There is a lot on the web about including ZEND, but I still don't get how to simply use it (without a skeleton) (In this case I only want to use `Zend\Dom\Query`)

I would like to:
1) Simply include the complete ZEND 2.3 library in a single application
or
2) Include a single ZEND 2.3 module

I'm using NGINX, but actually I just want to include it via PHP. Any hints, tips and or links?

What I did was:

```
include('./library/Zend/Dom/Query.php');
$c = curl_init($u);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($c);  
$dom = new Zend\Dom\Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('.foo .bar a');
...
```

Error is:
`Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Dom_Query' not found in /SOMEDIR/myfile.php on line 12`

Comment: The class name is `Query` within the namespace `Zend\Dom`. It's not named `Zend_Dom_Query`. You need to instantiate it with `new Zend\Dom\Query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to include it via PHP is :

**1.** Make sure that the Zend directory is on your php `include_path`. Assuming Zend directory is in the `library` folder you'll have something like this in your `index.php` file:

```
$path= array();
$path[] = '.';
$path[] = './../library';
$path[] = get_include_path();
$path= implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$path);
set_include_path($path);
```

**2.** Now just include `Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php` first and then use it to load other classes. You can do this :

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
'fallback_autoloader' => true,
 ));
$autoloader->register();
```

With the `$autoloader->register()`, you don't need to include files each time you want to call classes. You have just to instanciate your classes :

```
$dom = new Zend\Dom\Query($html);
```

Comment: Yep, this is it, I'm also looking at @foozy's composer example

Comment: Zend\Loader component probably will be moved out from the repository with release of ZF3. See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6285

Comment: What is the "Zend directory"? I'm using the ZendSkeletonApplication.

Answer (score 4):

[Zend Dom](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendDom) and all of other Zend Framework 2 components developed independently from the framework's itself. All of them maintained separately and there are custom repositories exists for this components, respectively.

I think that the best way of using this components without framework's itself, using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). We're living in open-source era and the year is 2014. All you need is making a search on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) instead of trying to use Zend Dom (or any 3rd party library) via manually including/requiring into the codebase. Please use composer and follow the [PSR standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

To integrate the composer into your very own application, open the console and simply type:

```
cd /path/to/your/project
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

After installation, use this command to add `zend-dom` dependency in your project:

```
php composer.php require zendframework/zend-dom:2.3.*
```

Now anywhere in your code, you can type `new Zend\Dom\Query()` to create a new dom query instance. (I'm assuming that you already read the [autoloading process](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is actually where I'm stuck. Now I have: `require_once './ZEND/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php'; $loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true)); $loader->register();` so with composer I can remove the require_once?

Comment: With composer you can remove all of that code. Instead you just include composer's autoloader instead (somewhere early in your script)

Comment: Yes, Tim is right. You dont need to use zend's loader. Just require the composer's autoload file which is located in the vendor directory. Please see the last link in my answer.